# Retrieving the attribute value from XML via different XPath

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following xml which is given to me and which I am passing in my XSLT for transformation purposes..

```
<Report xmlns:fpml="http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/confirmation" 
    xmlns="http://www.eurexchange.com/EurexIRSFullInventoryReport" 
    name="CB202 Full Inventory Report">
    <reportNameGrp>
        <CM>
            <acctTypGrp name="A4">
                <ProductType name="Swap">
                    <currTypCod value="EUR">
                        <rateIndex name="EURIBOR">
                            <rateIndexTenor name="6M">
                                <idxSource>EURIBOR01</idxSource>
                            </rateIndexTenor>
                        </rateIndex>
                    </currTypCod>
                    <currTypCod value="GBP">
                        <rateIndex name="LIBOR">
                            <rateIndexTenor name="1Y">
                                <idxSource>LIBOR01</idxSource>
                            </rateIndexTenor>
                        </rateIndex>
                    </currTypCod>
                </ProductType>
            </acctTypGrp>
        </CM>
    </reportNameGrp>
</Report>
```

I have developed the following XSLT for this, which i will later be using for transformation purposes, too. In the below XSLT I am trying to retrieve the values from the above XML:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:fpml="http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/confirmation" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:eur="http://www.eurexchange.com/EurexIRSFullInventoryReport">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/eur:Report">
        <Eurexflows>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="eur:reportNameGrp/eur:CM/eur:acctTypGrp/eur:ProductType/eur:currTypCod/eur:rateIndex/eur:rateIndexTenor" />
        </Eurexflows>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="eur:rateIndexTenor">
        <EurexMessageObject>
            <CCPTradeId><xsl:value-of select="eur:CCPTradeId/@id" /></CCPTradeId>
            <novDateTime><xsl:value-of select="eur:CCPTradeId/eur:novDateTime" /></novDateTime>
            <feename><xsl:value-of select="eur:CCPTradeId/eur:feeType/@name"/></feename>
            <feePayAmnt><xsl:value-of select="eur:CCPTradeId/eur:feeType/eur:feePayAmnt"/></feePayAmnt>
            <feeCurrTypCod><xsl:value-of select="eur:CCPTradeId/eur:feeType/eur:feeCurrTypCod"/></feeCurrTypCod>
            <feeDate><xsl:value-of select="eur:CCPTradeId/eur:feeType/eur:feeDate"/></feeDate>
            <idxSource><xsl:value-of select="eur:idxSource"/></idxSource>
            <rateIndexTenorname><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></rateIndexTenorname>
            <rateIndexname>
                <!--<xsl:value-of select="eur:report/eur:reportNameGrp/eur:CM/eur:acctTypGrp/@name/eur:ProductType/@name"/>-->
                <xsl:for-each select="eur:report/eur:reportNameGrp/eur:CM/eur:acctTypGrp/eur:ProductType/eur:currTypCod">
                    <xsl:value-of select="eur:rateIndex/@name" />
                </xsl:for-each>
            </rateIndexname>
        </EurexMessageObject>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now as you can see that in above XSL I want to retrieve the value of attribute `<rateIndex name>` which is not coming ideally. The value of `<rateIndexname>` should be `EURIBOR`, `LIBOR`.

Please advise how I can retrieve the value of the `name` attribute on the `rateIndex` element. Please explain what went wrong in my XPath applied in my XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

Within your template, you are currently positioned on a `rateIndexTenor` element. The `rateIndex` you wish to get the name for is the parent of this. So, you could use this expression, to replace the `xsl:for-each` which is unnecessary here, as there is only one parent:

```
<xsl:value-of select="parent::eur:rateIndex/@name"/>
```

This can be simplified to this, where `..` is a short-hand for the parent node.

```
<xsl:value-of select="../@name"/>
```